# Use privoxy to forward traffic based on IP similar to Proxifier

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, privoxy

My colleague shared his configuration. He is using a Mac. He is connected to a VPN using "open-vpn". Then he uses Proxifier to forward traffic to proxy.test.cloud:2128 as seen in the image below.

Proxifier settings:

[image: proxifier settings]

I am using Linux with open-vpn and privoxy as Proxifier is not available for Linux, but none of the traffic gets forwarded to the proxy.

```
privoxy config /etc/privoxy/config
forward 10.120.144.* proxy.test.cloud:2128
forward 10.120.145.* proxy.test.cloud:2128  
forward 10.122.0.* proxy.test.cloud:2128
forward 10.130.0.* proxy.test.cloud:2128
forward 10.120.161.* proxy.test.cloud:2128
forward 10.120.200.* proxy.test.cloud:2128
forward 10.120.160.* proxy.test.cloud:2128
forward 10.68.9.* proxy.test.cloud:2128
```

Comment: Found this tool on github https://github.com/m0hithreddy/Proxifier-For-Linux, it is working but only for http.